# Classifying essential singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to figure out the process for showing why the function $\cos(1-\frac{1}{z})$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$ without using knowledge of the Laurent expansion. I know the process should be to rule out the possibility of removable singularities or poles, but do not know how to do this for this function.

Attempt 
I was thinking I would show since $$\lim_{z\to 0} |\cos(1-\frac{1}{z})| \text{ DNE } $$ since the function oscillates between $1$ and $-1$ for $z$ near zero for positive values, this rules out the possibility of a pole since the limit is not $\infty$ and the singularity is not removable since the limit is not finite.Is this the correct approach? What are some other ways, to show that zero is an essential singularity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z_n:= \frac{1}{1-n \pi}$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ and $f(z):= \cos(1-1/z).$

Then $z_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and

$$ f(z_n)= (-1)^n$$

for all $n$. This shows that $z=0$ is not a pole of $f$ and not a removable singularity of $f$.

Comment: Thanks. I am still confused on why you choose $z_n=\frac{1}{1-n \pi}$ to be the sequence you take the limit to approach zero as?

Comment: Is it because $z_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?So the sequence of points is approaching the value of interest?Also in general should you show two different sequences approach two different values as they approach $0$?But in this case it isn't necessary because the one sequence does not exists?

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos\left(1-\frac1z\right)=\cos1\cos\frac1z+\sin1\sin\frac1z
=\cos1\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^{-2n}}{(2n)!}
+\sin1\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^{-2n-1}}{(2n+1)!}.$$
This is a Laurent series expansion with infinitely many terms with
negative powers, so the function has an essential singularity at $z=0$.

Comment: I need to find ways to show it without using laurent series but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt:
$\lim_{z\to 0}f(z) =\lim_{z\to 0}\cos(1-1/z)$ and $\lim_{z\to 0}1/f(z)=\lim_{z\to 0}1/\cos(1-1/z)$

both do not exist. Can we conclude now the singularity $0$ is an essential singularity?